# Pinging a windows machine on a network without a router/server

Tags: windows-11, ethernet, ping

I need to check the infrastructure in some office to see if the Ethernet sockets are functional. The office is currently vacant so there are no routers or servers available to me. Only two laptops with windows 11 running on them. Is there a way for me to set one of them as a ping server for that purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Responding to `ping` does not need a special server; it's built-in functionality in every OS – it's just blocked by Windows' default firewall settings.

You need to run `wf.msc`, then enable the two "ICMPv4/v6 Echo Request" rules; they're listed under "Core Networking Diagnostics" in Windows 11 (or under "File/Printer Sharing" in older Windows versions, but they still allow the exact same thing).

If the firewall cannot be configured, then you can still make ARP queries using the `arping` tool or maybe using some kind of "ARP scanner". (There is no firewall configuration; every device *has to* respond to those.)

Comment: But I wouldn't need some DHCP server to make them speak with each other? They can speak with each other directly?

Comment: @Yotam if you connect them with a cross-over UTP cable (not to be confused with the standard straight UTP cable), they will be able to talk to eachother after you do an ipconfig on both computers. They should have a 169.254 address but they should be able to see each other. Also, if you have a spare network switch, you can connect both with straight UTP cables too and talk to eachother the same way.

Comment: @LPChip: When was the last time you had a laptop that required a cross-over cable?

Comment: @u1686_grawity honestly, it was as long ago as I did not had any spare switch, hub or router. more than 20 years ago. Since then, I never needed it.

Comment: @LPChip Right, the only device I have that requires cross-over cable is an old Cisco router made in 2003. Every PC made since that has MDI/MDI-X auto detection and I'd be willing to bet OP's laptop does as well, so it really doesn't matter what cable is used – especially for Gigabit Ethernet where all wires are bidirectional anyway... (One out of two having auto-MDIX is enough, if I remember correctly.)

Comment: After your comment, I did a bit of research, and that lead to a *mind_blown* kind of situation. :) Even at my knowledge level, you can still learn something new. :)